# my code wont excute a very basic javascript function

Tags: jquery

My code wont execute the `alert()` function. Can anybody help me? Here is the code:

hook.txt:

```
<html>
<div id="text">
  <a href="#" class="name">george lucas</a> &nbsp;
  <span class="fadetxt">knows</span> 
  <span class="subjectnames">physiology</span>
</div>
<div class="detail"></div>
</html>
```

knowledge.txt:

```
<html><p class="subjecttitle>Physiology</p></html>
```

javascript:

```
     $(document).ready( function(){
    $('#stdmatch').load("/hook.txt");
            $('.subjectnames').click(function(){
            $(this).alert("data");
```

`});
                  });`

Comment: It's always a good idea to use the debugging facilities provided by your browser (they all have them). In this case, you would probably find out right away that there is no `.alert()` method on `$(this)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@katie: You have to use `$.live()` in order to match the class which was generated via `$.load`:

```
$('.subjectnames').live('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   alert('data');
});
```

Since the class is on a `<span>`, I suggest you update `hook.txt` to

```
<div id="text">
    <a href="#" class="name">george lucas</a> &nbsp;
    <span class="fadetxt">knows</span> 
    <a href="#" class="subjectnames"><span>physiology</span></a>
</div>
<div class="detail"></div>
```

Answer (score 6):

use `alert("data");` instead of `$(this).alert("data");`

no need to use $(this) with javascript function.

there is no `.alert()` method in jQuery

EDIT :

Use this

```
$(document).ready( function(){
   $('#stdmatch').load("/hook.txt");
   $('.subjectnames').live('click', function() {
       alert('data');
   });
});
```

Comment: @katie: in your code you are using `$(this).alert("data");`. Just use `alert('data');`

Comment: @Gaurav  yes i changed that but still it doesnt work,can you please review the code again there are three files.Thank you alot.

Comment: @katie : as in you code,it still shows `$(this).alert("data");`.

Comment: @Gaurav think i am missunderstood,what i want is when i click on the word physiology in the hook.txt file,the alert () should be invoked...

Comment: @katie : then you need to use live. As my code or as @stealthyninja suggested.

Answer (score 0):

@Katie  when you use alert you dont have to us $(this).alert() just call alert("data") but

if you want your alert function to show data from the hook.txt file you need to call it in a call back function

```
 $('#stdmatch').load("/hook.txt",function(data)
     {

        alert(data);  


    });
```